# WYSIWYG editor does not work on textarea that are generated through ajax-php calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tinymce, html-editor

I have a textarea that i am generating it with ajax, but after textarea is loaded then that textarea is not converting to WYSIWYG Editor, but it is working on normal textarea, Please help to solve my issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
........
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "dashboard/show_data",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data){

        $('#demo').html(data);
........
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
    <section id="demo">
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

> show_data.php

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Call `tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});` in the succes function ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this

```
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
```

After you have put your HTML into the demo element. Otherwise Google how to use jQuery `on`. Your issue is mce editor needs to bind to the new dom element and wont if you dont tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at the point of execution of the ajax success function the tinymce editors have been initialized already.

The solution to this is easy. You just have to initialize the new editor on success:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "dashboard/show_data",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data){

          $('#demo').html(data);

          //put the initial init function here instead
          tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});

          // **or** better in case you know the textarea id use
          tinymce.init({ selector: "#textarea_id" });
........
```